# Samsung Keyboard Brightness Keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, laptop, brightness, samsung

So I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic). It's mostly working with my Samsung NP540U4E laptop, just having some trouble with the keyboard brightness change function keys.

```
dmesg | grep -i setkeycodes
```

shows me that the scancodes are e017 for brightness down (Fn + F9) and e016 for brightness up (Fn + F10).

```
xmodmap -pke
```

gives me the output (among other things)

```
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
```

which I think are correct commands because

```
xdotool key XF86KbdBrightnessUp
xdotool key XF86KbdBrightnessDown
```

change the keyboard brightness up and down. I then tried

```
sudo setkeycodes e017 237
sudo setkeycodes e016 238
```

which didn't work, but for some reason if I subtract 8 from the keycodes they work for keyboard brightness up and down but now I have another problem. My laptop doesn't register these keys being released so they both only work once as my laptop thinks they are still held. And I couldn't see a scancode for the release of the keys

Answer (score 2):

NP540? I think it's close enough to NP300 to try the following fix (worked for me on 12.04 and 14.04):

1. In `/etc/default/grub`, append two kernel options `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor` so the line looks like this (leave any previously existing options not related to acpi):

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```

   Then run

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
2. Blacklist `samsung_laptop` module by creating `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-np450.conf` with the following contents:

   ```
   blacklist samsung_laptop
   ```
3. Reboot, see if this works. If not, revert the changes (remove modifications to `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-np450.conf`)